# (php) boton submit solamente hace un refresh de la pagina

Tags: php, html, submit, form-submit

me explico,
tengo una base de datos mysql, y tengo que hacer una aplicacion php,entre las funciones esta el añadir entradas a la base de datos con un formulario, y los "pedidos" insertados se muestran en el listado de pedidos
aqui pongo primero la funcion que hace el insert en la base de datos y luego el formulario

estoy seguro que los campos de formulario no son el problema, pues he probado a quitarlos todos menos 1 a ver si asi al menos el hacer click en el boton no hacia simplemente un refresh, pero aun asi seguia igual

```
<?php

require_once "bd.php";

class pedidocliente
{
    private $db;

    function __construct()
    {
        $bd = new bd();
        $this->db = $bd->conectarBD();
    }

  
    

    function insertarpedido($id_PE,$producto,$id_PROV,$cod_cl,$dni_per)
    {
        
        try {

            $queryInsertar = "INSERT INTO pedidos (producto,id_PROV,cod_cl,dni_per)
                                 VALUES ('$producto', '$id_PROV', '$cod_cl', '$dni_per')";
            $respuestaInsertar = $this->db->query($queryInsertar);
           
            if ($respuestaInsertar) {
                echo "Libro creado correctamente";
                header("Location:index.php");
            } else {
                echo "Ocurrió un error inesperado al crear el pedido";
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo "Ocurrió un error: " . $ex->getMessage();
            return null;
            
        }
        }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
include "head.php";
?>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Crear nuevo pedido: </h1>
            <br>

            <?php
            require "pedidocliente.php";
          

            if (
       
                isset($_POST['producto'])
                && isset($_POST['id_PROV'])
                && isset($_POST['cod_cl'])
                && isset($_POST['dni_per'])
            
            ){
            
                $producto = $_POST['producto'];
                $id_PROV = $_POST['id_PROV'];
                $cod_cl = $_POST['cod_cl'];
                $dni_per = $_POST['dni_per'];
                $pedidocliente = new pedidocliente();
                echo $pedidocliente->insertarpedido($producto,$id_PROV,$cod_cl,$dni_per);
            }
            

            ?>
            <form id="insertarpedidoForm" target="insertarpedido.php" method="post">
     
           
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>producto</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="producto" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>id_prov</label> <br>
                <select name="id_prov">
  <?php

            $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","proyectobrian") ;
                  if ($conn)echo "conexion ok" ;
                 else echo "conexion ko";
                 $consulta="select id_PROV from proveedores";
                 $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
                       
                        while($lista=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
 
        ?>
                   <option value=" <?php echo $lista['id_PROV'];?>"><?php echo $lista['id_PROV'] ?> </option> 
                   <?php } ?>
   
                 </select>
             </div> 

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>cod_cl</label> <br>
                 
                 <select name="cod_cl" required >
        <?php

            $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","proyectobrian") ;
                  if ($conn)echo "conexion ok" ;
                 else echo "conexion ko";
                 $consulta="select cod_cl from clientes";
                 $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
                       
                        while($lista=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
 
                     ?>
                   <option value=" <?php echo $lista['cod_cl'];?>"><?php echo $lista['cod_cl'] ?> </option> 
                   <?php } ?>
   

                 </select>
                 </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>dni_per</label>
                     <br>

                    <select name="dni_per" required>
                    <?php

            $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","proyectobrian") ;
                  if ($conn)echo "conexion ok" ;
                 else echo "conexion ko";
                 $consulta="select dni_per from personal_de_transporte";
                 $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
                       
                        while($lista=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
 
        ?>
                   <option value=" <?php echo $lista['dni_per'];?>"><?php echo $lista['dni_per'] ?> </option> 
                   <?php } ?>
                   </select>

                </div>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Crear pedido</button>
            </form>
            <br>
            <a href="index.php"><button>Volver al listado</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cambia el target por action: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Answer (score 0):

Para que un formulario se puede enviar necesita el atributo action, por lo cual debes cambiar el target por action

```
<form id="insertarpedidoForm" action="insertarpedido.php" method="post">
```

Comment: desafortunadamente la cosa sigue igual ,al hacer click en el boton la pagina se refresca como si usases la tecla F5

Comment: Puede que tengas algún evento de JS que lo está ocasionando

Comment: no tengo codigo de java en los documentos,asi que eso no puede ser

Comment: No Java, sino JavaScript.

Comment: osea, no tengo nada de javascript en el codigo